# Problems with generics and casting in F#

Tags: .net, generics, casting, f#, type-conversion

Using a genome type implemented in a following way

```
type Genome<'T> (listIn : List<'T>)=
    member this.list = listIn
    member this.GetValues() =
        this.list
```

I ran into a problem while writing another code fragment.

```
type IMutation =
    abstract member MutateMethod: Genome<'T> -> Genome<'T>

type DoubleGenomeMutation() = 
    member this.Mutate = (this :> IMutation).MutateMethod
    interface IMutation with
        member this.MutateMethod(genome: Genome<'T>) = 
            let randomIndex = MyRandom.Next(0, genome.list.Length)
            printfn "%d" randomIndex
            let newValue = MyRandom.NextDouble(Parameters.LowerBounds.Item(randomIndex), Parameters.UpperBounds.Item(randomIndex))

            let (newGenomeList : List<'double>, _) = 
                List.foldBack (fun elem acc -> 
                match acc with
                | (l, 0) -> (newValue::l, -1)
                | (l, i) -> (elem::l, i-1)) (genome.GetValues()) ([], genome.GetValues().Length - randomIndex - 1)

            new Genome<'T>(newGenomeList)
```

I found it impossible to use the generics mechanism correctly here. The quoted sample effects in

```
Error   2   Type mismatch. Expecting a
    float list    
but given a
    List<'a>    
The type 'float' does not match the type ''a'
```

in line

```
| (l, i) -> (elem::l, i-1)) (genome.GetValues()) ([], genome.GetValues().Length - randomIndex - 1)
```

Casting a variable up or down was ofter described as solution in similar cases - unfortunately I was unable to fix my program this way. I would appreciate any direct help as well as any suggestions about the root of all problems.

Comment: I am betting you have a `open System.Collections.Generic` at the top and are creating some confusion with the list type there

Comment: Probably not at all. I am not using System.Collections.Generic anywhere, Only immutable F# lists.

Comment: What happens if you change the signatures from `List<'a>` to `'a list`?

Comment: Nothing exciting unfortunately. `Error 2 Type mismatch. Expecting a
    float list    
but given a
    'a list    
The type 'float' does not match the type ''a'`

Comment: What's the return type of `MyRandom.NextDouble`?

Comment: It is `double * double -> float`.

Comment: Got it. I was distracted by the `'a list` versus `List<'a>` thing from bitter experience of a hard to track down problem which I suspect John Palmer shared, but looking at the error properly it's clear that it's really complaining about the arguments not the container type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the source of `MyRandom`, but if I replace `MyRandom.Next` with an `int` as it looks like it should be and replace `MyRandom.Double` with a `double`, then I can reproduce your error.

The problem is that the return type of `MyRandom.NextDouble` is constraining the rest of the code inappropriately; `MutateMethod` is declared to be able to take *any* type argument, but then you use the `newValue` as part of the return list in the `(l, 0)` case which constrains the type of the other case too.

You may also have got a warning from `newValue` pointing out that it was constraining your `'double` type variable to be of type `float` which is another clue. Really `'double` should be `'T` as that's how the parameter is originally declared.

The error goes away if I replace the call to `MyRandom.NextDouble` with throwing an exception (which can have any result type), which confirms this diagnosis:

```
type DoubleGenomeMutation() = 
    member this.Mutate = (this :> IMutation).MutateMethod
    interface IMutation with
        member this.MutateMethod(genome: Genome<'T>) = 
            let randomIndex = 1 // MyRandom.Next(0, genome.list.Length)
            printfn "%d" randomIndex
            let newValue = failwith "foo"

            let (newGenomeList : List<'T>, _) = 
                List.foldBack (fun elem acc -> 
                match acc with
                | (l, 0) -> (newValue::l, -1)
                | (l, i) -> (elem::l, i-1)) (genome.GetValues()) ([], genome.GetValues().Length - randomIndex - 1)

            new Genome<'T>(newGenomeList)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems that if I specify the `IMutation` interface the way I did, any implementation have to be able to deal with any 'T type. But is there any solution that would allow the usage of multiple   specialized implementations (for example: one working only with doubles, one with ints and so on - with different logic inside)?

Comment: The cleanest way would be to define multiple `MutateMethod` members of the `IMutation` interface - I think you can share the name as overload resolution should be able to figure that out. You could also implement `MutateMethod` with a big match statement that does type tests, but it'd need a lot of boxing and unboxing to pacify the type-checker.